# Change shader values for multiple slots at the same time

Tags: materials, shaders

I want to adjust the skin roughness for a model in my scene. Since the whole skin is basically using the same shader, just with different maps, I wondered if there is a simple way to change a value for a selection of material slots at the same time. This would make things waaay faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare your shader in various ways so that they have a common, synchronized element. One is a custom group, so that modifying the contents of this group applies to all users of this group. Another is using drivers that all connect to a single custom property. Yet another is to just use a single material with things differing from object to object relying on UV maps or attributes...